# sum up time column in 2 different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Table1**

```
BufferTime(buffertimeID int(identity), bufferperiods int(minutes))
```

**Table2**

```
Reservation(resvID int(identity), resvdatetime datetime, buffertimeID int(FK))
```

How i gonna sum the `bufferperiods` and `resvdatetime` in a new column `'resvbookingtime'` using SQL view?

The 'resvbookingtime' is actually for viewing purpose. Should i did query in view?
Or in other way. Please help and explain to me.

[image: My SQL View]

note: buffertime = 120

I have done this, and what should I do in order to make the 'resvbookingtime' to display in time format only?

Thanks

Comment: By writing proper SQL query, I guess?

Comment: Do you mean adding those integer minutes `bufferperiods` to the `datetime` field `resvdatetime`? then use [`DATEADD(n, bufferperiods, resvdatetime)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms186819.aspx),  but how the two tables relate to each other?

Comment: yes, i have update the foreign keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here there is no foreign key in your BufferTime table. I have assumed that there is one key in BufferTime which refers to Reservation.

This sql should do the work for you.

```
    create view myview
    as SELECT r.resvdatetime, bt.bufferperiods, 
DATEADD(minute,bt.bufferperiods,r.resvdatetime) AS resvbookingtime
    FROM BufferTime bt
    Inner join Reservation r
    on r.resvId=bt.resvId
```